# How to compare 2 CSV files with only first 6 signs in groovy

Tags: csv, groovy

Please help with parse CSV to JSON from 2 files in groovy. I have 1st CSV like this (line numbers may be different each time):

testKey,status

Name001-something,PASS

Name002-something,PASS

Name003-something,FAIL

CSV2 (list of all testkeys but with different names of keys:

Kt,Pd

PT-01,Name007-something1

PT-02,Name001-something2

PT-03,Name003-something3

PT-05,Name002-something5

PT-06,Name004-something5

PT-07,Name006-something5

This code is parsing only the same value but I need also testKey even when first 7 signs are the same in both files. Maybe substring(0,6)?

```
import groovy.json.*    

def csv1 = '''
testKey,status
Name001-something,PASS
Name002-something,PASS
Name003-something,FAIL
Name004-something,FAIL
'''.trim()

def csv2 = '''
Kt,Pd
PT-01,Name007-something1
PT-02,Name001-something2
PT-03,Name003-something3
PT-05,Name002-something4
PT-06,Name004-something5
PT-07,Name006-something6
'''.trim()

boolean skip1st = false

def testMap2 = [:]
//parse and bind 1st CSV to Map
csv2.splitEachLine( /\s*,\s*/ ){
  skip1st ? ( testMap2[ it[ 1 ] ] = it[ 0 ] ) : ( skip1st = true )
}

def keys
def testList = []
csv1.splitEachLine( /\s*,\s*/ ){ parts ->
  if( !keys )
    keys = parts*.trim()
  else{
    def test = [:]
    parts.eachWithIndex{ val, ix -> test[ keys[ ix ] ] = val }
    //check if testKey present in csv2
    if( testMap2[ test.testKey ] ){
      test.testKey = testMap2[ test.testKey ] // replace values from CSV2
      testList << test
    }
  }
}  

def builder = new JsonBuilder()
def root = builder {
    testExecutionKey 'DEMO-303'
    info user: 'admin'
    tests testList
 }

builder.toPrettyString()
```

result is:

```
{
    "testExecutionKey": "DEMO-303",
    "info": {
        "user": "admin"
    },
    "tests": [
        
    ]
}
```

In a result I need something like:

```
{
    "testExecutionKey": "DEMO-303",
    "info": {
        "user": "admin"
    },
    "tests": [
        {
            "testKey": "PT-02",
            "status": "PASS"
        },
        {
            "testKey": "PT-05",
            "status": "PASS"
        },
        {
            "testKey": "PT-03",
            "status": "FAIL"
        },
        {
            "testKey": "PT-06",
            "status": "FAIL"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You could use `.substring()`

Comment: in which place in code?

Comment: where you only want to use the first 6-7 chars of your key

Comment: i need to compare CSV1.testKey with Pd.CSV2  but only 6 first digits

Comment: ```//check if testKey present in csv2
 if( testMap2[ test.testKey.substring(0,7) ] ){
   test.testKey = testMap2[ test.testKey ] // replace values from CSV2
   testList << test
 }    ```                                                         not working

Comment: Please edit your question and update your code.  Also be specific about "not working".

Comment: edited code, where can I put substring?

Comment: do you have any idea how i could solve it?

Comment: ok I've added substring   :csv2.splitEachLine( /\s*;\s*/ ){
  skip1st ? ( testMap2[ it[ 1 ].substring(0,12) ] = it[ 0 ] ) : ( skip1st = true )
}

def keys
def testList = []
csv1.splitEachLine( /\s*;\s*/ ){ parts ->
  if( !keys )
 keys = parts*.trim()
  else{
 def test = [:]
 parts.eachWithIndex{ val, ix -> test[ keys[ ix ] ] = val }
   //check if testKey present in csv2 (only first 12 digits)
 if( testMap2[ test.testKey.substring(0,12) ] ){
   test.testKey = testMap2[ test.testKey.substring(0,12) ] // replace values from CSV2
   testList << test
 }
  }
}

Comment: Please edit your question and update your code

Comment: last my comment solved a problem